# Hardware RAID configuration on Linux

Tags: linux, hardware-raid

I have a linux server with a RAID controller and 6 HD (4TB each). I want to mount a calculus server and I am thinking in two possible configurations:

1. Hardware RAID 10 using 6 HD (only 12TB available from 24TB) and then install linux
2. Hardware RAID 10 using 4 HD (only 8 TB available from 16TB), one HD (4TB) as hot spare (if one HD fails) and the last HD (4TB) for backup

Which one is better? Or maybe you can suggest me another configuration.

Another question I have in mind? What is better, to mount the RAID and then to perform the HD partitioning (to get `root`, `home` and `usr` directories) or make first the disk partitioning and then mount the hardware RAID on some partitions?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What specific hardware RAID solution is this? That's an important detail.

Comment: It is a LSI Mega RAID SAS-MFI (in a Supermicro Server)

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as how you have hardware RAID, my advice is:

Divide the hardware RAID in two logical partitions:

1. Your OS
2. Volume group for any number of logical volumes

You will then get a `sda` (say 50 or 100 GB) on which you can install your OS and an `sdb` on which you run `pvcreate`, `vgcreate` and then 'lvcreate' (read up on logical volumes).

I would not put the backups on a separate disk. If one sector on the disk fails, your entire backup might be broken. If you use my suggested setup, you have the redundancy of your entire array everywhere, still have separated file systems so that corruption on one does not destroy something else.

As for the spare; if you just have this one array, you can have the spare be for all your data. Also, look into configuring spin-down for the spare.

This is general advice, and my need fine-tuning to suit your particular setup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Halfgaar. I have a doubt (probably because I do not know so much about RAID management). After I create a Hardware RAID, it is like I have only one disk. Is that right? Then, when I go to install the Linux OS I can divide the hardware RAID into two logical partitions, one for my OS and another one for storage purposes. My doubt lies in the use of <code>pvcreate</code> and <code>vgcreate</code>. What partitions should I have to include in the Volume Group? Are you referring to all partitons I want to create on second logical partition (for example Work1, Work2,...)?.

Comment: @ManuelRamón you can configure your hardware raid to give you two disks, that is what I meant. Then you can create LVM on the second one of those. This also alleviates partition size limitations (if using MBR), because you're not using partitions in your volume group.

Comment: Ok, I see. I will try it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1) 2nd option is more fault tolerant.
2) You should arrage hardware RAID first, then pattition but not vice versa.